# sed text string modification by prepending a fixed value

Tags: sed

I have a csv file with 500 lines and 8 columns. One column is for the office phone number. About 200 of them are in the form -1234 but need to be 123-456-7890.

Each of the 200 instances have a different last four as they are desk phone numbers. The area code and exchange part are the same for all. So as an example, we have three data points:

```
-2329
-5679
-8891
```

These three items need to be converted to the full phone number so will need to look like:

```
212-598-2329
212-598-5679
212-598-8891
```

Anybody have the sed wizardry to pull this off ?

An example line of data looks like:

```
Bill,Smith,Mr.,bsmith@mydomain.org,bsmith,-5315,800-878-5554,\N,\N,\N,\N
```

Comment: you should list at least one row of your csv as example.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{$6="212-598"$6}1' OFS=, input.file
```

Using `,` as the input and output field delimiter it is simple to access the sixth field and prepend the static value.

Answer (score 0):

alternative with sed

```
$ sed 's/,-/,212-598-/' missing_phone

Bill,Smith,Mr.,bsmith@mydomain.org,bsmith,212-598-5315,800-878-5554,\N,\N,\N,\N
```